Can I check if my phone is rooted (no dev options) with Pixel 6Pro?
Just bought a Pixel 6 Pro 2d ago; updated to Android 14.
Started installing (same apps as on old phone).
The banking app forbids me to use fingerprint as it insists my phone is rooted.
Never have done rooting, my other bank app doesn't warn about anything, neither does Google Pay or any google security check.
Tried to check About Phone, according to alphr,but I can't find any place that tells whether I have official or non official version -- there is simply no such section.
Seems suspicious. Here's the screenshot of my About Phone:

should it have any other section saying whether it's official Android or not?
There is no dev options in Options either, and searching for them yields nothing.
Thanks in advance!

The screenshot from alphr is taken from a Samsung device, but AFAIR Pixel doesn't have such info. Try root checker apps or terminal apps (scroll below on alphr). Otherwise, try turning on the Developer Options and then off again to reset the value. While it's not technically root, developer options sometimes can be considered sensitive to security. Last, you may want to check the app reviews if there's any issue with Android 14, or contact the bank...

The build number in your screen shot corresponds to the Apr update so it looks offcial //To enable developer options tap the build number (under about phone 7 times or more). Also check USB debugging under dev options, if enabled, disable that (some banks like Citibank check that too) // Then disable developer option as suggested by @AndrewT

Is this a new phone or used? If it's a used phone use the Android Flash Tool to flash a factory image//If it's a used phone Force Flash all partitions should be checked as also wipe device to make it clean

When powering up the phone do you get an screen for ~ 3 seconds that warns about an unlocked bootloader?

@beeshyams Thanks, I tried enabling/disabling dev options, didn't seem to make any difference for the bank app. And it should be a new phone, unless our company supplier is fiddling and getting some shady phones off the counter. Not totally impossible, but very unlikely.

@Robert Nope, I just restarted it and didn't see anything like that.

@Gnudiff: I see these options 1. Check with the app developer or try an older version of the app from a reliable source 2. Return the phone 3. Flash with Android Flash Tool as suggested earlier//If it was my choice I'd go with option 3 while perusing option 1. You'd lose data, that's fine compared to you facing similar situation in future

Thanks to all for your helpful comments, I've done the fastboot and the device appears to be locked OK, so bank at fault.

The easiest way to check if your phone has been tampered with, is to verify booloader lock status.

Turn off your phone fully.
Press and hold Volume Down and Power button together for a few seconds.

Not you should be greeted with a fully black screen that says "Fastboot mode" on the top, looking exactly like this:

The part that you're interested in is the part that says Device Status:

Unlocked means your device has been tampered with and it's likely not running fully verified firmware. It's likely that the phone IS rooted and, more importantly, it might contain some dropped malware. You should reinstall the OS ASAP.

Locked, the bootloader is verifying the signature of the OS and confirming that it's coming from Google - that means that your phone almost certanly IS NOT rooted and your banking app is falsly accusing you of rooting the phone. (Note that banks using poor quality root detection methods that trigger on less popular phones is a very common occurence, especially right after Android OS updates. It's likely it's their fault, not yours.)



You can now exit fastboot mode by pressing the power button next to "Start" option. It'll boot normally.

If your device has been unlocked, you can use https://flash.android.com to reinstall official Google firmware on your phone and relock the bootloader to reenable verification of the Google signed OS on the phone.

Thank you, the phone  confirmed my device is locked, and I can forward the screenshot to bank so they fix their app.
